# ConversationScoped in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am migrating an application from Thorntail to Quarkus. It uses the the conversation scope annotation in a bean that provides the token information during all the rest api request to any service interested in it. But in Quarkus documentation it says the conversation scope is not implemented. Is there a similar feature I can use?

Here is what I want to do:

```
@Path
@ApplicationScoped
public class FruitsResource {

    @Inject FruitsService fruitsService;

    @POST
    public int post (Fruit fruit) {
         return fruitsService.post(fruit);
    }
}

@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
private class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject AuthorizationHolder authorizationHolder;

    @Override
    public void filter (ContainerRequestContext request) {
        String token = request.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        Authorization authorization = createAuthorizationFromToken(token);
        authorizationHolder.setAuthorization(authorization);
    }
}

@ConversationScoped
private class AuthorizationHolder {

    private Authorization authorization;

    @Produces
    public Authorization getAuthorization () {
        return authorization;
    }

    public void setAuthorization (Authorization authorization) {
        this.authorization = authorization;
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
private class FruitsService {

    @Inject Authorization authorization;
    @Inject EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void post (Fruit fruit) {
         // do some complex validation with the authorization object
         ...

         // persist object
         entityManager.persist(fruit);
         entityManager.flush();
         return fruit.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe your usecase in more detail? Because from what you wrote, it seems RequestScoped would be enough for you. In any case, SessionScoped should be available in Quarkus, and you could implement conversations on top of that.

Comment: I added a more detailed description. That is the exact code in Thorntail. How can I achieve the same in Quarkus using SessionScoped? @Ladicek

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Authorization` header present in each request? I suppose it is (or should be), in which case just using `@RequestScoped` instead of `@ConversationScoped` should work. This is probably the best thing to do, anyway.

In case the header is only present in "first" request and subsequent requests in the same session can reuse the token, then you can just replace `@ConversationScoped` with `@SessionScoped`. I think enforcing the header to be present in all requests would be better, though.

Finally, if you'd really like to emulate conversations, you can do something like this (not tested, not even written in an IDE, just from the top of my head):

```
@SessionScoped
private class AuthorizationHolder {
    private ConcurrentMap<String, Authorization> authorizations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Authorization getAuthorization(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return authorizations.get(getConversationId(request));
    }

    public void setAuthorization(ContainerRequestContext request, Authorization authorization) {
        this.authorizations.put(getConversationId(request), authorization);
    }

    private String getConversationId(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> query = request.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();
        return query.getFirst("cid");
    }
}
```

However, as I said above, I really think you should make the bean `@RequestScoped` and force the clients to send the `Authorization` header with each request.

Comment: The authorization is sent with each request. Even so, replacing ConversationScoped with RequestScoped does  not work. I created a test that shows this behaviour here: https://github.com/AmsterdamFilho/quarkus-poc.git
Just run in quarkus:dev, add any token in swagger-ui and execute the endpoint

Comment: For the SessionScoped solution you suggested, every endpoint call would have to inform a query parameter named cid? @Ladicek

Comment: That's how the conversation scope works, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Actually, just replacing ConversationScoped with RequestScoped didn't work because of the method annotated with Produces. When also the method was annotated with RequestScoped, then it worked.

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't think of that. I'm still a CDI newbie :-)